# Are my test Facebook "Likes" private when in sandbox mode?

Tags: facebook, sandbox

I'm trying to integrate my website with Facebook (and other social media).

So far, I have:

- created a [new app](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)
- left the app in Sandbox mode
- added meta-data to my webpage (as describe on [this post](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/optimise-your-website-facebook))
- added FB ['Like'-plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)
- created some test users

I had assumed that while the app is in **Sandbox mode** that I would be able to click the "Like" button without this being visible to my friends, however my wife mentioned that she saw the "Like" in her FB activity stream.

Questions to those with experience of integrating sites with Facebook:

- Is this expected, or should my "Like" have been invisible to my friends while in sandbox mode?
- If I want to test the app in private, do I have to just use the test users to stop spamming my contacts with unfinished content?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know while an app is in sandbox mode nothing is published to your wider facebook audience.

Only developers / testers / admins of the app can see the content you post eg. Likes

Check if if your wife is a tester of your app, that might be why she's seeing the likes.

Comment: Good point about my wife being a tester. I had set her up as a test, but she was still in pending state as she hadn't accepted. Even stranger, a friend of mine then liked - he certainly wasn't set up with any roles. Can anyone recommend any best practices for testing Facebook integration (without sharing with the world)?